# Android Studio: "My First App" does not work

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm definitely new to Android development.

I'm following along this tutorial: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html, and it seems I can't run the app on the AVD because I don't see the application launcher icon nor the "Hello world" text. It does not show in the Apps Menu nor in the "Manage my apps" window.

I'm running an emulator for a 3.2 QVGA phone with API Level 22 (Android 5.1.1) using the armeabi-v7a ABI.

Here's the code I got:

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.gregory.myfirstapp" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MyActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

**MyActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.gregory.myfirstapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class MyActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

**activity_my.xml**:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" 
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <TextView android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**menu_my.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" 
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_settings" 
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

Please help me out here!

Comment: Sometimes the Google AVDs can be slow. Once the AVD is fully up and running, try running the app from your IDE again.

Comment: I now got it; what on earth was I thinking? I need a virtual emulator running before I can run my app! Thank you.

Comment: You should try `Genymotion` emulator, it is much faster. You just need to install Genymotion and also add the Genymotion plugin to Android Studio.

Comment: Virtual emulator will start automatically if it is not started when run the android app

Comment: Hmm, maybe I should have read my StackOverflow notifications in advance... I got the app running on the same day that karaokyo commented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem with my Android Studio. I've started the application in the Debug-Mode (The green bug next to the play button). Sometimes the emulator is very slow, so you have to wait 5 to 50 seconds after unlocking the virtual phone. Normally the app should open up itself on the screen, and after the first run the app should appear in your App Menu.

Comment: Even with the virtual phone opened up, for some reason I have to click on "Run" again for the app to be installed on the virtual phone and run it. (I do have an Android phone of my own, but I decided not to risk running the app there.)

Comment: I always test the apps on the virtual one, if all is fine I export the .apk and install it on my real phone and test it again.